# Initial indexes of sorted elements of ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

The following code implements sorting of `nfit` in ascending order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> nfit = new ArrayList<Double>();

    nfit.add(2.0);
    nfit.add(5.0);
    nfit.add(1.0);
    nfit.add(8.0);
    nfit.add(3.0);

    // Sort individuals in ascending order
    Collections.sort(nfit);

    System.out.print(nfit);

}
```

The output is:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0]
```

My question is how to get initial indexes of sorted elements? In this example the answer to my question would be the following:

```
[2, 0, 4, 1, 3]
```

How can I get these indexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the ArrayList and sort, then use indexOf.

```
ArrayList<Double> nfit = new ArrayList<Double>();
nfit.add(2.0);
nfit.add(5.0);
nfit.add(1.0);
nfit.add(8.0);
nfit.add(3.0);
ArrayList<Double> nstore = new ArrayList<Double>(nfit); // may need to be new ArrayList(nfit)
Collections.sort(nfit);
int[] indexes = new int[nfit.size()];
for (int n = 0; n < nfit.size(); n++){
    indexes[n] = nstore.indexOf(nfit.get(n));
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexes));
```

If you wanted the indexes in an ArrayList,

```
Collections.sort(nstore);
for (int n = 0; n < nfit.size(); n++){
    nstore.add(n, nfit.indexOf(nstore.remove(n)));
}
Collections.sort(nfit);
```

That will result in one sorted ArrayList nfit, and one ArrayList  of indexes nstore.

Edited: In the for loop

```
for (int n = 0; n < nfit.size(); nfit++){
    nstore.add(n, nfit.indexOf(nstore.remove(n)));
}
```

The loop count must be iterated over n and not on nfit
Find the corrected code:

```
for (int n = 0; n < nfit.size(); n++){
    nstore.add(n, nfit.indexOf(nstore.remove(n)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the`ArrayList` then sort the copy. After that use `indexOf` method passing element of sorted array and invoking on original `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are unique, you can use a `Map<Double, Integer>` to hold the value and initial order. You just need to sort the map keys and get the correspond value of each key.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions: 1) if you are wedded to ArrayList, you'll need to use an Iterator to build the index list of the solution set.  2) Switch to a Map with the value and the order (which can be changed by sorting).

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation of mergesort implements a method 'indexSort' that does just that without messing with the input array.
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/Merge.java.html
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/javadoc/Merge.html#indexSort(java.lang.Comparable[])

Comment: Please include relevant portion of the codes in your answer with some descriptions on how they solve the problem. Answer containing only reference to external link will become obsolete if those links are broken. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Also, all the answers other than mine beat the purpose of the question. The complexity of rearranging the indices is itself O(N^2), greater than of the sorting in the first place.

Comment: You can quote someone else's code as long as you attributed it back to the author. http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing And try stick to what was being asked; OP never state complexity as part of the original question..

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is always your friend. You can use it to sort the array and at the same time keep track of original array indices. It will also work when you have multiple similar elements in your array.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class BubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int count = 5;
        ArrayList<Double> array = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int[] indices = new int[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
            array.add(rnd.nextDouble() * count);
            indices[i] = i;
        }
        ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>(array);
        bubbleSort(values, indices);
        System.out.println("Unsorted input array   :" + array);
        System.out.print("Sorted   input array   : ");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(array.get(indices[i]) + " " );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    private static void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Double> values, int[] indices) {
        for(int k = 0; k < values.size(); k++) {
            for(int l = k + 1; l < values.size(); l++) {
                if(values.get(k) > values.get(l)) {
                    double temp_value = values.get(k);
                    values.set(k, values.get(l));
                    values.set(l, temp_value);
                    int temp_index = indices[k];
                    indices[k] = indices[l];
                    indices[l] = temp_index;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I answered this question after this many years is that the  [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15790218/5412470) will fail if you have multiple elements with similar values because in `indexes[n] = nstore.indexOf(nfit.get(n));`, `indexOf` method is always returning the first occurrence of the specified element which results in an incorrect indices array while having similar elements in the input array.

Last, copy and paste the code in `BubbleSort.java` and then run `javac BubbleSort.java && java BubbleSort` to compile and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

If your list have duplicate values below code will work to get index of initial list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0));
    ArrayList<Double> arrr = new ArrayList<>(arr);
    int[] index = new int[arr.size()];

    Collections.sort(arrr);
    final double min = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    System.out.println(arr);
    System.out.println(arrr);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
      index[i] = arr.indexOf(arrr.get(i));
      arr.set(arr.indexOf(arrr.get(i)), min);
      System.out.print(index[i] + " ");
    }
  }
```

Output on console:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0]
0 3 1 4 2 5 6
```